# Best practices for writing a log for a Java server

Tags: java, logging, server, format

I'm looking for some advice on best/common practices with writing a log for a game server I wrote in Java (first time with server/client concept and I've never done anything with logging). I've tried some Googling, but the keywords involved are kind of vague and not coming up with any answers to my questions.

I have a server with users, game lobbies, and games. I think that I should create a log to keep a history of everything that happens on the server. And in this log I think I should record status changes of both the server itself (startup, shutdown, commands being processed), and socket connections (new/lost clients, incoming/outgoing messages).

I'm not sure if that's the best thing to do, or instead/also have a log with more human readable messages like "Bob781 joined lobby #4." or "microman12 beat sun44 in a game."

- Should I write logs to the console or to a file? (2 separate files?)
- What formats are best or most commonly used? Should they be the same formats?
- I've come across the "[Common Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format)", is this the best format choice for socket connections? Can it be used for the server statuses?
- Should I use something in java.util.logging or just output the strings myself?

Comment: What's the point of write logs to the console on a server? Nobody will see it. Total waste of time even trying. Besides, server programs run in the background, so they don't *have* a console to write to.

Comment: i always look for existing solutions before starting from scratch. I know for a fact that having logs output to different files depending on the type of log message it pertains to is extremely helpful. this also brings up the question of how much logging do you want to do? perhaps at some size create another file or overwrite the existing one... lots of possibilities.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I guess I really just want to do enough logging to be able to learn the basics of it.

Comment: @Andreas I think you're right about that. But I was thinking it'd be good during the development process so you can monitor and verify things happening on the server as you continue building it.

Comment: @tribes891 That's for development, but your question is about how to setup/configure logging on a server. The ability to *configure* logging is why you should use a logging library such as [Apache Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html), ...

Answer (score 0):

You always want to look for existing solutions before starting from scratch. When you use/create the logging, I would suggest the following tips based on my experience

1. Make sure you can reliable retrieve the logs whenever you might need them.
2. Make it easy to find a log file based on what you're looking for. For example if there is a problem with a specific game lobby, you should be able to easily navigate to the file or directory of files that pertain to that game lobby in question. Nothing worse than having to parse a huge gigantic log file...
3. Make each logging message meaningful. Don't just log stuff for the sake of logging. You will want to be able to read a log message and know relatively where in the server code that message is coming from. This will help later down the road when you run into bugs in your server code.
4. Have each log message time stamped at the point it's created and not when it's written to the log file.